# How to change the content-type of a request which will be made by ClientCredentialsResourceDetails?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Right now, I am trying to change the `content-type` of a request which will be raise by **ClientCredentialsResourceDetails**
**(**`org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`  **)**

***Expected content-type :-*** i.e. **form/data** or **multipart/form-data**

But right now i can see/do only this one,

```
ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
```

this code allow me only to pass the data through the following `content-type`,

```
content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

so, i want to change it.

can any one give me an idea ? how to do this ?

any help appreciate...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client Credentials flow is defined in RFC 6749, "[4.4. Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)", and "[4.4.2. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2)" says as follows.

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the following parameters using the **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP request entity-body:

So, it is hopeless to expect that Spring Security and other OAuth client libraries provide means to change Content-Type of a token request using Client Credentials flow to any other value than "application/x-www-for-urlencoded".

Comment: i would like to pass some data through the POST-payload but if we could not change the content-type then OAuth server denied to do so, even if we have provided the right paryload, that's main issue for me as of now.

Comment: Do you mean your authorization server does not comply with the specification? If so, why don't you try other implementations?